# Understanding OpenGL boiler-plate

Tags: winapi, opengl

I have just started learning OpenGL using the tutorials on Nehe, and so far I am following them ok.

How necessary is it to understand all the setup code?  The tutorial is using the Win32 api to set up a window, and I think I understand about 50% of the code.

Is it vital to understand all of the system calls and OpenGL boiler-plate initialization stuff, or can I just crack on without getting heavily lost down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a subjective question, but my opinion (and that of many others) is that you don't need to write all that platform-specific boilerplate.

If you use another library like GLUT or SDL, it becomes much easier: let the library worry about setting up a window, and then you can focus on learning OpenGL. Unless of course you *want* to learn the WinAPI, but it seems like your priority lies elsewhere.

The NeHe tutorials are somewhat out of date; I've pointed people towards [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) as a good source to get started, but there are many other "modern" OpenGL tutorials as well. It uses GLUT.

Comment: As pointed above: NEHE are a bit old... those tutorials teach fixed pipeline OpenGL... but now we should learn/teach shader based pipeline. I recommend: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/ and http://openglbook.com/

Comment: +1 to looking at 'Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming', it is a fantastic resource.